# bash, issue on listing amazon s3 element

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list and to echo all the files having yesterday's date in their names, on a amazon s3 bucket.

I know I can do:

```
s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/`date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"`*
```

which is working just fine, but I need to do several stuff on these files, one bye one.

So my code is:

```
for file in $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")*)
do echo $file
done
```

it also works fine but instead of retrieve me just the file name it also give me for every single element: the date it was uploaded and its weight:

```
s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436434_ip-10-0-1-36_android.log.gz
2015-07-20
23:55
6180965
```

How can I just retrieve the file's name? ie: s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436434_ip-10-0-1-36_android.log.gz

Comment: is piping it through `head -n 1` an option, or do you need a clean solution?

Comment: what does it do exactly? well a clean solution would be better, but im taking everything that works... thanks @Fiximan

Comment: `head` will just print the head of a file, i.e. the first few (standard is 10) lines, while `-n NUMBER` will let you select how many exactly. So you would not change what is being retrieved, but what you actually use from it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `s3cmd`, these days it is recommend to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has great features such as `--query` (to control output) and access to every AWS API call.

Here's a sample that would fit your need:

```
for file in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKET-NAME --prefix `date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"` --query 'Contents[*].Key' --output text);
do echo $file;
done
```

Breaking it down:

- `aws s3api list-objects` outputs information about Amazon S3 object
- `--bucket` specifies the Amazon S3 bucket
- `--prefix` specifies the start of the Amazon S3 object name (which works well for your use-case)
- `--query` describes the output fields required (here just the object Key, which is the filename)
- `--output` is one of JSON, text, table

See: [list-objects CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html)

As simpler version of listing objects is available (`aws s3 ls BUCKET-NAME`) but it has a fixed text output, like `s3cmd`.